# Get address/port of ServerSocket that a Socket is trying to connect to? (Java)

Tags: java, sockets

I can't word this well, so let me give you an example.
If my code is:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("1.2.3.4", 80);
```

and then I run two methods like:

```
System.out.println(socket.getAddressOfHost());
System.out.println(socket.getPortOfHost());
```

I want it to return:

```
1.2.3.4
80
```

Is this possible and what are the names of these methods?

Comment: have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html (for java 7)

Comment: `getLocalPort()` and `getLocalAddress()` is what you want I think.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the Javadoc?

Comment: @hoyah_hayoh: those return the IP/port that the `Socket` is locally bound to, not the remote IP/port that the `Socket` connects to.

Answer (score 0):

After the `Socket` is connected to the server, those values can be retrieved using the [`Socket.getInetAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress()) and [`Socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getRemoteSocketAddress()) methods:

```
InetAddress addr = socket.getInetAddress();
// InetAddress does not expose port numbers...
System.out.println(addr.getHostAddress());
System.out.println(addr.getHostName());
```

```
InetSocketAddress sockaddr = (InetSocketAddress) socket.getRemoteSocketAddress();
InetAddress addr = sockaddr.getAddress();
System.out.println(addr.getHostAddress());
System.out.println(addr.getHostName());
System.out.println(sockaddr.getPort());
```

Refer to the [`Socket` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) for more details.

Comment: You need to rewrite your first paragraph. The connection happens in this constructor, not afterwards. No 'can then' about it. If the connect fails, the constructor throws an exception, so the object won't exist, so there is nothing to call `getInetAddress()` and friends with.